# How to cancel photo burst

Tags: photos.app

Saw an answer but it was 2 years old and thought there might be changes.

Is it possible to disable the "burst" feature on photo's???

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't disable taking photos with burst mode.

In `Settings` you can only disable the upload of burst photos to your **iCloud** account but you can't turn off burst mode.

I would recommend going to Apple's [Feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/) page and providing your feedback that you'd like them to include this as an option.  It's possible Apple will put it on the product roadmap if many people suggest it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt and thorough answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Please be sure to accept the answer so others with a similar question can find the answer.

Comment: You just click the checkmark next to the answer.  See this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers